# How can I access WWW from behind a LAN to WAN router cascade?

Tags: networking, router, lan, tomato, wan

I am trying to set up a LAN to WAN router cascade using ethernet cable between a Belcom (Router 1) and a Linksys WRT54G running Tomato 1.28 (router 2). I am wanting to do this to improve parental access control by using the great functionality offered by Tomato. Unfortunately I can't simply use the Linksys for my DSL modem as it does not support PPPoA.

Configuartion:

Router 1 - Belkin acting as DSL connection to WWW

```
IP Address: 192.168.2.1
Net Mask:   255.255.255.0
DHCP:       Enabled
DHCP range: 192.168.2.2 - 192.168.2.50
Wireless:   Disabled
WAN DNS (ISP):  212.19.xx.xx and 212.19.xx.xx
```

ROUTER 2- Linksys wireless Access Point

```
IP Address: 192.168.1.1
Net Mask:   255.255.255.0
DHCP:       Enabled
DHCP range: 192.168.1.12 - 192.168.1.100
WAN IP Address: 192.168.2.51
Gateway:    192.168.2.1
Mode:       Gateway
```

With this configuration I can ping from inside the second secure network (192.168.1.x) to the primary interface network (192.168.2.x) and to the WWW (212.159.xx.xx) but I cannot get a browser from any device connected to the internal (192.168.1.x) network to connect to the WWW.

This configuration will allow me to access the WWW from any device connected to the primary interface network (192.168.2.x).

What have I missed out? Been at this for a few days and can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Put router 1 in bridge mode?

Comment: Note that when NAT is in play, you cannot generally access addresses/services on the exterior routers WAN interface from within the LAN. unless a feature called NAT Hairpinning is enabled. it is not available on most commercial routers.

Comment: Yep, bridge mode if your isp supports it. Or dmz to your second routers wan address.

Comment: DMZ from primary router to secondary router using IP 192.168.2.51 did not work, WWW remained inaccessabile

Answer (score 0):

It seems your router2 is holding an IP on WAN that's not assigned by router 1. Look at the `DHCP range` of router1, it's `192.168.2.2 - 192.168.2.50` while your router2 has `192.168.2.51`.

All you need to do is to make sure the router2 WAN is getting IP using the DHCP of router1. My ASUS router has that configuration named `Automatic IP`

Comment: https://www.wikihow.com/Connect-Two-Routers confirms that to complete a LAN-To-WAN cascade requires the secondary router to have a static WAN IP address that is outside of the DHCP range of the primary router

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem using advice from [Linksysinfo.org](https://www.linksysinfo.org/index.php) post and is specific to the Tomato software:

From the second router, under Advanced → DHCP/DNS, I added the following to Dnsmasq Custom Configuration:

```
no-resolv
server=8.8.8.8
server=8.8.4.4
```

The `no-resolv` directive tells DNSMasq to *ignore* every other source of DNS servers, wherever they may come from. The only DNS servers used are those listed.